# Giphy API in Discord Bot async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord, giphy

I started to program a Discord-Bot, he hasn't that much functions at the moment. So at the moment im working on the command "!gif", so I type that command with an word (here it is "spider"), as a reponse I get a gif with a Spider-Tag.

So here is my Discord-Code:

```
if(command == "gif"){
   message.channel.send(modSearchGif.searchForGif("spider"));  
}
```

modSearchGif is a module which is implemented in this .js script.

The Module looks like this:

```
var GphApiClient = require('giphy-js-sdk-core')
const client = GphApiClient(process.env.GIPHYTOKEN)

const searchForGif = (gifName) => {
client.search('gifs', {"q": gifName, "limit": 1})
.then((response) => {
   var gif = response.data[0].url;
   return gif;
 })
 .catch((err) => {
  return err;
 })
}

module.exports.searchForGif = searchForGif;
```

So its really easy, if the command "gif" is writen in the Discord-Channel, the Bot is calling the module and give it the parameter "spider".
Then the client search for this parameter in the giphy database and returns a json script. This is a Promise, if the Promise is fullfilled the gif is returned to the mainscript and will be send to the Discord-Channel.

Here is the Problem, the Promise call is async, so the Discord Command "message.channel.send" is executed before the promise is fullfilled, so the message is undefined and i get an error "Cannot send empty message".

I want the message.channel.send executed when the gif is returned, not earlier.

I really have no clue about this.
Have you guys some ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this, as `then/catch` also returns a Promise

```
if(command == "gif"){
   var searchPromise = modSearchGif.searchForGif("spider");

   searchPromise.then((gif) => {
     message.channel.send(gif);
   })  
}
```

For this to work `searchForGif` should `return` the Promise, i.e.,

```
const searchForGif = (gifName) => {
  return client.search('gifs', {"q": gifName, "limit": 1})
         .then((response) => {
           var gif = response.data[0].url;
           return gif;
         })
         .catch((err) => {
           return err;
         })
}
```

Comment: thank you, how can I return the Promise? This is very new for me.

Comment: Just put `return` in front of `client.search` like in the second code snippet. Then the function `searchForGif` returns a Promise, which can be used according to the first code snippet.

Comment: wow thank you, it works like a charm! Awesome, didnt thought about the objective you can return.